# netbeans c++ cross-plattform (mac & linux) at the same time with git

Tags: c++, linux, git, macos, netbeans

I am currently wondering how I can solve the situation, that I want to work on a C++ project from multiple devices with different OSs. So my idea was to just push my .cpp and .h files up. So I tried to clone it and create a project with exisiting sources files. I was hoping Netbeans would realize where to put the files in the right project subdirectories (like header files/source files). However it doesn't work because it needs the Makefile. Which is pointless though to push the Makefile up to git, since it contains information about the previous OS.

Is there a way that Netbeans will be smart enough to figure just out to put the files in the right folders and then I can compile it from scratch without existing Makefiles from the previous operation system?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you considered using the same relative structure and a smarter makefile that can build different targets using different toolchains? That way all Netbeans needs to know is `make <insert target here>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing what @user4581301 was talking about for many years.

IMPORTANT: The Netbeans project type must be "C/C++ Project with Existing Sources".

The Makefile contains an `ifeq` statement, so it works differently on Linux and Windows:

```
MAIN = tc0001

ifeq (${OS},Windows_NT)
  include ${MAKELIBHOME}/MINGW32.inc
  include ${MAKELIBHOME}/WINDOWS.inc
else
  MAKELIBHOME := ${HOME}/host/lib/make
  include ${MAKELIBHOME}/GCC.inc
endif

build: ${MAIN}

clean:; rm -fr core *.o latest*
```

The `MAKELIBHOME` directory is a place where I store various pieces of makefiles (`MINGW32.inc`, `GCC.inc` etc.). The `MAKELIBHOME` is an environment variable on Windows, but the Netbeans on Linux doesn't understand such kind of environment variables, so I have to assign this variable right in the `Makefile` before including the pieces.

All is stored in the Git repo.